# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "ambiguo" y "equívoco"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, sinónimos

[**Ambiguo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2Hrlgpx) aparece definido por el DRAE como:

> 1. adj. Dicho especialmente del lenguaje: Que puede entenderse de varios modos o admitir distintas interpretaciones y dar, por consiguiente, motivo a dudas, incertidumbre o confusión.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que, con sus palabras o comportamiento, vela o no define claramente sus actitudes u opiniones.
> 3. adj. Incierto, dudoso.

mientras que [**equívoco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G0lqyoJ) es:

> 1. adj. Que puede interpretarse en varios sentidos, o dar ocasión a juicios diversos.
> 2. m. Equivocación, confusión.
> 3. m. Palabra cuya significación conviene a diferentes cosas; p. ej., cáncer, vela, cabo.

Para las dos palabras se indica que puede entenderse de varios modos e inducir confusión, lo que a mí me produce incertidumbre y confusión.

Si hablando con el señor A le digo:

> **El señor B está herido porque le ha mordido su perro.**

se puede interpretar como que al señor B le ha mordido el perro del señor A o el perro del señor B. Puede que para mí o para B no haya duda sobre qué perro ha sido, pero para A (u otra persona que lea o escuche) sí puede haberla. En un caso así, la frase ¿es ambigua o es equívoca?

Comment: Como adjetivos, tiene pinta de que son sinónimos. Sin embargo, yo diría que la frase es ambigua y puede dar lugar a equívocos.

Comment: Según yo, _equívoco(a)_ es más específico que _ambiguo(a)_: en el primero las dos interpretaciones posibles son contradictorias.

Comment: @Rafael: los ejemplos que propone la RAE para _equívoco_, como "cabo" o "vela" no me parece que sean contradictorias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(dejo de lado la evidente diferencia si se toma* equívoco *como sustantivo, que creo que queda fuera del sentido de la pregunta)*

Luego de una búsqueda (no me atrevería a decir exhaustiva, pero sí empeñosa), concluyo que **no existe una diferencia *normativa***. Dicho de otra manera, dudo que se pueda encontrar casos en que la elección de una sobre otra pueda ser considerada sin lugar a dudas errónea (o más correcta).

Sin embargo, el campo semántico y etimológico de estas palabras **sugiere** (y ha dado lugar a) **distinciones** incluso entre gente culta. Estas distinciones no están recogidas por el DLE, y por lo tanto, pueden ser consideradas cosa de gustos (o de pedantería injustificada, mirada desde el otro extremo) [*comentario al margen: aunque* crear *y* criar *tengan significados distintos, provienen de la misma raíz, y lo que son aparentes derivados --[creatura](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BD4sgLR) y [criatura](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BFzjeMc)-- son sinónimos a pesar de la distinción que podría esperarse por la especialización que sufrieron los respectivos verbos*].

- Un ejemplo de distinción es el que da Alfonso Pérez en [Una Mirada al Ser](https://books.google.cl/books?id=eZvCAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA292&ots=m6m7dDw53j&dq=diferencia%20entre%20ambiguo%20y%20equivoco&pg=PA292#v=onepage&q=diferencia%20entre%20ambiguo%20y%20equivoco&f=false) (aunque para mi gusto limita el significado de la ambigüedad para conseguir una diferencia artificial).
- Otro ejemplo de distinción viene más directamente del campo semántico: ***equívoco*** está estrechamente relacionado con [***equivocar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G0jWiIZ), que el DLE toma como derivado del primero. Esta última palabra tiene más claramente un sentido de **errar**, tomar como cierto lo que no es, mientras que ***ambiguo***, como citas, sólo explicita el sentido de **confuso** y el posible error sería sólo una implicancia *posible* (no necesaria, por lo tanto): en este sentido, *lo* ambiguo *induce a duda o confusión, mientras que lo* equívoco *induce a error*.

En latín, [ambĭgŭus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D44%3Aentry%3Dambiguus) significa *dudoso, incierto, poco confiable*, y al parecer sólo con el tiempo llegó a su significado moderno (recogido en la primera acepción que da el diccionario). Por su parte, [aequĭvŏcus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D27%3Aentry%3Daequivocus) se traduce incluso al inglés como *ambiguo* y *equívoco* (y también como *con significados parecidos*, ¿= sinónimo, idea afín?), corroborando que la distinción -que en algún momento pudo haber habido- hoy ha perdido mucha fuerza (si no es que toda).

Comment: Me ha encantado la distinción que haces entre _exhaustiva_ y _empeñosa_ :)

Answer (score 0):

Es mi opinión que a primera vista yo interpretaría, o asociaría, "ambiguo" con algo sin precisión, y "equívoco" con algo equivocado.  El hecho es que la falta de precisión puede conducir a equivocos.  Es posible que ésta sea la razón por lo cual ambas palabras pueden referirse a malentendidos.  Sin embargo, yo continuaré usando equívoco y equivocación para el significado de errado, y ambiguo para el significado de dudoso.

Answer (score -1):

Del [diccionario Oxford](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/ambiguo):

> 1. [comportamiento, expresión, palabra] Que puede entenderse o
>   interpretarse de diversas maneras.
>
> "hizo un gesto ambiguo con la boca; la coalición mantiene una postura
>   ambigua respecto a este tema; ‘voy al colegio por mi hijo’ es una
>   frase ambigua"
>
> sinónimos: equívoco
>
> 2. [persona] Que actúa con poca decisión, seguridad o firmeza. "no acaba de concretar lo que tiene en mente, peca de muy abstracto,
>   ambiguo e indeciso"

Comment: Si vas a copiar el contenido de una web ([de esta](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/ambiguo), en concreto), debes indicarlo. Échale una ojeada a [How to reference material written by others](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) y [edit]a la respuesta.